# syslog shows 2 users and shows usb device when I didn't use one

Tags: server, usb, permissions, bluetooth, cron

So a lot of the `syslog` code history was deleted just before I was typing this up but here is some of it:

```
SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.ally.atspi.Registry

Created slice User Slice of (my username)
Starting User manager for UID 1000
```

Showing 2 users in `syslog` one is `UID 108` the other is mine. Also I come up as `C2`.

Also `bluetooth` was being used when I wasn't. On one start up it appeared in the tab where it previously wasn't so I uninstalled but then later was appearing in the log service as being used.

USB device being used in `syslog`, says the type of USB but I haven't used one. I tried to disable USB use but it says access denied.

In the `auth.log` it says:

```
CRON [3076]: pam_unix (cron:session): opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

The cron sessions appear periodically every 10/11 hours.

Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 3):

Thats a perfect output, to explain it a bit I'll take it step by step:

1. `SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.ally.atspi.Registry`
   This one seems to be a system daemon, not really sure what he does.
2. `Starting User manager for UID 1000`
   This is the UID of your users group.
3. `UID 108`
   This is the syslogs group UID.
4. `CRON [3076]: pam_unix (cron:session): opened for user root by (uid=0)`
   This just informs you that the cron is running its normal routine jobs as `root`.

Hope this will shed some light for you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask-Ubuntu, if my answer was helpful to you and answered your question you can accept it by clicking the check-mark beside it.

Comment: So I checked if there are any listening processes and it showed - PID/program name

Comment: Add it into your question and i will try to see if i can make sense out of it.

Comment: So I checked if there are any listening processes using sudo netstat -tulnp and it showed - PID/program name udp 0 0 0.0.0.:34913 0.0.0.0* foreign address 789/avahi-daemon r 0 0 udp 0.0.0:5353 0.0.0.0* foreign address 789/avahi-daemon r udp 0 0.0.0.0:631 0.0.0.0* foreign address 898/cups browsed udp6 0 0 :::35787  :::* udp6 789/avahi-daemon:r 0 :::5353 :::* 789/avahi-daemon: r           Sorry to carry on the  question. @Videonauth

Comment: Thats harmless, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) for more information about.

Comment: There you go, changed the link around in my last comment